# Genesis WordPress Sticky Footer via CSS/jQuery

Tags: jquery, wordpress, css, wordpress-theming, sticky-footer

Alright, Folks, I'm driving myself batty with this one.

For a client, I've been making loads of sites with Genesis & WordPress. However, on certain sites the theme doesn't look fantastic without a sticky footer.

`The problem is that` no good sticky footer seems to be around specifically for Genesis. This results in what you see [here](http://kangabloo.com/) on the homepage:

Essentially, the content isn't long enough, so the footer doesn't rest at the bottom, usual suspects, etc. I've tried editing functions.php in conjunction with CSS, I've tried raw CSS fixes, and I've also tried some jQuery footers. No such luck.

The fix I'm using now that works is this:

```
/* Sticky Footer Fix - It's like "Dirty Dancing" & "Footloose" Had a Baby . . . Mmmmm . . . */

* {margin:0;padding:0;} 

/* must declare 0 margins on everything, also for main layout components use padding, not 
vertical margins (top and bottom) to add spacing, else those margins get added to total height 
and your footer gets pushed down a bit more, creating vertical scroll bars in the browser */

html, body {height: 100%;}

#wrap {height: 100%;}

#inner {min-height: 79%;
    margin-bottom: 66px; /* must be same height as the footer */
    overflow: hidden;}  

#footer {position: relative;
    margin-top: -66px; /* negative value of footer height */
    height: 66px;
    clear:both;}
```

It works alright, but it's just not accurate enough for my taste. You can view what it's doing at [this site](http://laurenerion.com/)

`So here's my question:`

**What's the best way to make a footer stick to the bottom of the page in Genesis when content is not long enough?**

I'm amazed it's been this dang hard, so I'm assuming I'm just missing something. Surely other people are doing this and have a fix running.

Any thoughts (CSS or jQuery) are appreciated! Seriously done losing sleep over this one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, I've sorted this one out myself!

It's not a perfect solution, in that it uses jQuery and not pure CSS. But if you're using the Genesis Framework and need a sticky footer fix, it's incredibly simple.

Just download this plugin I've put together, install it as normal, and then activate. Assuming you've followed the instructions within the README.txt, everything will be gravy!

Thanks to @Shelton for the help, as well as to this article by Chris Coyier (http://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/jquery-sticky-footer/).

Here's the link to the actual plugin:

http://kangabloo.com/Kangabloo/Public/GenesisStickyFooter1.0.zip

Happy theming!

Answer (score 1):

This worked great - I added this to the custom CSS stylesheet and - sticky footer:

```
.site-footer {  
     position: fixed;
     bottom: 0px !important;
     width: 100%;
     min-height: 100px; // change to height of your footer
     padding-top: 20px; // change padding to desired amount
     padding-bottom: 20px;
     left: 0;
     margin: 0;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

```
body{
    position:relative;
    height:100%
}
footer{
    position:absolute;
    top:100%;
    margin-top:-66px;
}
```

Comment: Sadly, this did not work, though thank you for the input! I believe I've isolated the issue to two things:

1. The footer is contained within the central #wrap element, which prevents it from working with this sort of fix.
2. I'm using Genesis Widgetized Footer that's creating PHP beyond my head as far as removing the items and placing them outside the wrapper. 

Are there any thoughts on how to incorporate a quick PHP fix to remove the footer, widgets, etc. from the whole, then perhaps use something like 

http://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/jquery-sticky-footer/

to finish the job off?

Comment: When you position something absolutely, it will base it's position on the nearest ancestor element with a relative position. So if the footer is in a wrapper with position:relative, the footer will rest in the top left corner of the wrapper, until you give it a different position. But if the wrapper position is static, it will ignore that wrapper and go to the next ancestor it finds with a relative position. Make sense? So the wrapper shouldn't really matter. Static is the default position, so just don't assign any position to the wrapper and you should be good.